# SVG cannot set width and height in firefox

Tags: firefox, svg

i am tying to solve this problem that is very annoying....

a simple structured html, with an svg element with the width and height of 700px:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="gameZone">
        <div id="background">
        <svg id="svgRoot" width="700px" height="700px">
            <circle cx="355" cy="600" r="10" id="ball" />
            <rect id="pad" height="15px" width="150px" x="280" y="670" rx="10" ry="20"/>
        </svg>
        </div>  
    </div>
</div>
```

the question is why the hell the svg is displyed without the width and height in firefox?
in chrome and ie its working 100%;

please help me solve this problem.

here is an screenshot of the problem:  http://shaharmesh.hostingsiteforfree.com/differance.jpg

Comment: What's the problem? Firefox and Opera display pretty much the same here.

Comment: i have added an photo for best understanding of the problem i get.
http://shaharmesh.hostingsiteforfree.com/differance.jpg

Comment: i need the svg element to be 700X700 on all browsers...

Comment: Where's the light blue background coming from? It isn't in your testcase.

Comment: i have updated the screenshot in hope that somebody understand the problem - http://shaharmesh.hostingsiteforfree.com/differance.jpg

Comment: So the debugger gets the size wrong. Why is that a problem?

Comment: the problem is that i program a game in javascript +html5 + svg,
and i need to set game stage (svg) to be 700X700.
i did it by simply add an svg element to my html5 document:
<svg id="svgRoot" width="700px" height="700px"></svg>
the problem is that firefox do not render the svg element to be 700x700.... why like this?

Comment: You are complaining that the debugger shows the svg size incorrectly and I'm asking why that would affect you. You don't need the debugger to run your game.

Comment: the debugger show correct values... i wiil upload today a working version of the game and you can see what i am talking about.

Comment: Yes, it would be a lot better if your testcase actually showed the issue.

Comment: The link to the screenshot is not working anymore. Can you provide a jsfiddle?

Answer (score 0):

Firefox debugger show the size as same as the result by svgRoot.getBBox(), the actual svg content bounding size.

To avoid the problem, place a invisible rect which has the same size as the canvas, or other shapes to take up the top-left and bottom-right corners of the svg.

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="gameZone">
        <div id="background">
        <svg id="svgRoot" width="700" height="700">
            <rect width="100%" height="100%" stroke="none" visibility="hidden" pointer-events="none" />
            <circle cx="355" cy="600" r="10" id="ball" />
            <rect id="pad" height="15" width="150" x="280" y="670" rx="10" ry="20"/>
        </svg>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```